# How can I output the territories array with craft.i18n?

Tags: localization

I found this code in the [Craft documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/locale-data-from-templates):

```
{% set localeData = craft.i18n.getLocaleData() %}
{% for month in localeData.getMonthNames() %}
    {{ month }}
{% endfor %}
```

What I need is the whole list of countries (from Ascension Island to Zimbabwe).
I tried `.getTerritories()` but it doesn't exist:

```
{% set localeData = craft.i18n.getLocaleData() %}
{% for country in localeData.getTerritories() %}
    {{ country }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Yii doesn't expose a way to grab all of the territories for a given locale by default.

I've just added it to Craft 2.2, though.  So when that comes out, you'll be able to do this:

```
$localeData = craft()->i18n->getLocaleData('en_us');
$allTerritories = $localeData->getAllTerritories();
```

Comment: Not exactly. With your code I get a list of all locales but not of all territories (array) in craft/app/framework/i18n/data/en.php. Another question: Is there a page in the documentation where I can find an overview about all craft.i18n.* methods?

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood the question. Do you want to list the territories array for each locale in craft/app/framework/i18n/data or just en.php?  We don't have craft.i18n documented yet, but we should have something for you sooner than later.

Comment: I need the territories only from one locale (en.php). I use the list in a select in a contact form.

Comment: With Craft 2.2 I can output the values but not the corresponding keys. I get "146, Italy" instead of "it, Italy". The keys are consecutive numbers not country codes like de, it, en...

Comment: It doesn't look like territories is included in craft 3 i18n, right?